# How to Uncheck all checkboxes with a button. Input tag in child and button in parent. react - table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-table

Im using react-table, See the following codesandbox ([here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrl1m3vom3))

So, I'm trying to bind an unCheck function to a button so all checkboxes I've selected will become unchecked. The button is in the parent component and ALL the checkboxes are in a child component called **MyCheckbox**.

I've tried so many things and It seems like refs will do. ( if you find another way I'm all ears)

Technically I've tried the following in another app [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l45nwq4lvl) and it works, but in this case the function and the ref are inside the **same** component., so I'm guessing I have to pass refs? or maybe a callback. (sorry I'm kinda new at refs and Yes, I know they are bad practice)

this is the piece that is failing:

```
 unCheck() {
   let ref = "ref_";
   this.refs[ref].checked = !this.refs[ref].checked;
 }
```

how do I pass refs from child to parent? so my Uncheck function can use it.

PD.
Also, the **ToggleAll ()** function selects and DESELECTS ALL checkboxes. this is a prop that react-table provides. however this is more of a on/off switch. I would like **ONLY the OFF** part of it. In my actual app im using redux too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
 unCheck = () => {
    this.setState({ selection: [] });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also...

```
unCheck = () => {
    // let ref = "ref_";
    // this.refs[ref].checked = !this.refs[ref].checked;
    this.state.selectAll = true;
    this.toggleAll();
  };
```